# NVIDIA-SMI failed after working for months

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

After working nicely for several months on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, TensorFlow stopped working spontaneously. Probing my 3 Titan X GPUs with NVIDIA-SMI yields:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver.
Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers as suggested on several places online, with the same result. Please help!

Comment: Try doing a "vim /var/log/apt/history.log" and see what are the latest upgrades/updates installed. Most likely the last one has broken something